# Sending Form Data to Node Server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, forms

I am trying to send some form data to an endpoint.

Here's my client side code:

```
<form name="form" action="http://localhost:8080/geodata" method="post"> 

        <label for="minlat"> MinLat: </label>
        <input type="text" name="MinLat" value="0"><br>
        <label for="maxlat"> MaxLat: </label>
        <input type="text" name="MaxLat" value="1"><br>
        <label for="minlong"> MinLong: </label>
        <input type="text" name="MinLong" value="0"><br>
        <label for="maxlong"> MaxLong: </label>
        <input type="text" name="MaxLong" value="1"><br>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"> Submit <span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span></button>

        </form>

    <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#form")
            .submit(function(event) {

                var formData = {
                'minLat'            : $('input[name=MinLat]').val(),
                'maxLat'            : $('input[name=MaxLat]').val(),
                'minLong'           : $('input[name=MinLong]').val(),
                'maxLong'           : $('input[name=MaxLong]').val()
                 };

                $.ajax({
                    url: $form.attr('action'),
                    data: formData,
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    processData: false,
                    type: 'POST',

                    }).done(function(data) {

                        console.log(data);
                    });
                event.preventDefault();
            });
    });
    </script>
```

I have an enpoint on the server side code (express.js):

```
var express = require("express");
var path = require("path");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser"); 

var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
  // Initialize the app.
var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, function () {
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log("App now running on port", port);
});

app.post("/geodata", function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send("hi");
});
```

I wish to send this form data to the endpoint /geodata, and use that data to send a result back to the client side. First of all, when I hit submit, I get an empty {} in my terminal (which is the server side request.body). I was expecting form values in this request.body but don't receive them. How do I make sure my form values are being sent?

Secondly, res.send("hi") re-directs my initial page to a new page and prints "hi" there. Since I had made an ajax call, shouldn't the response just be logged and the webpage stays on the initial page?

Comment: Are you using any sort of middleware in Express to parse the body?

Comment: @Markasoftware :
I included the rest of my code on the server side above. I am using body parser.

Comment: If Possible Try Using `Formidable` - A node.js module for parsing form data, especially file uploads. (https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable)

Answer (score 2):

Change the form action to '/geodata'(the endpoint)

also you dont need to make a ajax request as HTML5 forms will perform the request itself if a tag() is pressed/clicked.

after you click summit your page will become what ever response that is sent back from '/geodata' route
and req.body will return a object that represents the form data

Comment: I am trying to make a request such that I am not re-directed to another page, hence ajax. It's also not working as I have coded it since I get redirected to a new page to view the response the server sends back

Comment: i forgot to mention about setting headers... you need to set a header since your page is not change route. just add res.set('content-type','application/json')

Answer (score 0):

dataType: 'json' means you are expecting json data from the server. remove dataType, and add this

```
  data : JSON.stringify(formData),
  contentType: 'application/json',
```

contentType would be the type of data you are sending to the server.

Comment: thanks for that correction. Unfortunately, I still just get an empty {} for console.log(req.body)